# Checking XML with XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to check XML with XSD,

But currently I am getting this error:

`The Content Of 'null' Is Invalid. Element 'element' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often.`

I need to check each field if it is not empty: ID, name and data from attributes?

**The XML I use:**

```
<DataEXP>
    <Item>
        <!-- Unique ID for this product - only instance of this ID in whole feed -->
        <ID>
            <![CDATA[DM1054]]>
        </ID>
        <!-- In name included info, that differs this product from other products. Typical order is: BRAND type of product MODEL-->
        <name>
            <![CDATA[Apple iPhone]]>
        </name>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>
                    <![CDATA[Functions]]>
                </name>
                <values>
                    <value>
                        <![CDATA[touchscreen]]>
                    </value>
                    <value>
                        <![CDATA[touchID]]>
                    </value>
                </values>
            </attribute>

        </attributes>
    </Item>
</DataEXP>
```

**The XSD I use:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2018 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="Item">

                <xs:complexType>

                    <xs:sequence>

                        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" />

                    </xs:sequence>

                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

If some one can find the error in the **XSD** 
Thanks

Comment: Your schema defines an element with the name `Item` to be a sequence of elements with the name `ID`. But your input data contains much more: `name`, `attributes`, `value`. I think it should be obvious, that this will not work. What is the question? Do you want to fix the input data or the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Your XSD was incorrect, and as it is very strict it requires more fields to be in there in order to validate your XML correctly against your XSD.

I set up a very minimal version of the XSD which would validate your XML correctly without errors. Bare in mind that I have not yet checked how many times items can occur (except for value in values), and of what type they are.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2018 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="DataEXP">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Item">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ID"/>
                            <xs:element name="name"/>
                            <xs:element name="attributes">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="attribute">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                  <xs:element name="name"/>
                                                  <xs:element name="values">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                      <xs:sequence>
                                                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="value"/>
                                                      </xs:sequence>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                  </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```